# Set legal hold on Azure storage account container with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

How to set legal hold on Azure storage account container in ARM template?

When setting immutable blob storage policy Azure portal allows you to choose from legal hold and Time-base retention. According to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-06-01/storageaccounts/blobservices/containers/immutabilitypolicies) arm template supports immutable blob storage. However only requests with immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays are accepted. When trying without setting it, I am getting:

> Missing at least one of the following properties 'immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays,allowProtectedAppendWrites'

Or:

> immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays must be set before setting allowProtectedAppendWrites

Weirdest - without properties block in immutabilityPolicies (as below) request fails with InternalServerError:

> {
> "status": "Failed",
> "error": {
> "code": "UnexpectedException",
> "message": "The server was unable to complete your request."
> }
> }

```
{
  "name": "testsa/default/testcontainer/default",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/immutabilityPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01"
  // ,
  // "properties": {
  //   // "immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays" : 10,
  //   // "allowProtectedAppendWrites": false
  // }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but when dealing with storage account immutability, apiVersion 2019-xx-xx did not work for me. I had to use apiVersion 2021-xx-xx e.g. 2021-06-01. Hope this helps others

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, the resource type `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/immutabilityPolicies` just can be used to create **time-based retention policies**. Meanwhile, when creating time-based retention policies, the parameter `immutabilityPeriodSinceCreationInDays` is required. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blobcontainers/createorupdateimmutabilitypolicy) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage#allow-protected-append-blobs-writes).

Besides, at the moment, Azure ARM template does not provide any resource type to create set legal hold policy. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutability-policies-manage?tabs=azure-portal) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blobcontainers/setlegalhold). So I suggest  you use  [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template)s in template to implement tit.